# How to examine vsdo vars?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, gdb, vdso

I would like to inspect the contents of vsyscall_gtod_data (all the time keeping related information that is needed to make clock_gettime() work).

I'm using gdb to single step through the assembly code of __vdso_clock_gettime() and I'm looking at the following section:

```
   0x00007ffff7ffaa71 <clock_gettime+129>:  cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbx]
   0x00007ffff7ffaa73 <clock_gettime+131>:  je     0x7ffff7ffaa47 <clock_gettime+87>
   0x00007ffff7ffaa75 <clock_gettime+133>:  jmp    0x7ffff7ffaa56 <clock_gettime+102>
   0x00007ffff7ffaa77 <clock_gettime+135>:  pause  
   0x00007ffff7ffaa79 <clock_gettime+137>:  mov    r12d,DWORD PTR [rbx]
=> 0x00007ffff7ffaa7c <clock_gettime+140>:  test   r12b,0x1
   0x00007ffff7ffaa80 <clock_gettime+144>:  jne    0x7ffff7ffaa77 <clock_gettime+135>
   0x00007ffff7ffaa82 <clock_gettime+146>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0xffffffffffffd5fc]        # 0x7ffff7ff8084
   0x00007ffff7ffaa88 <clock_gettime+152>:  mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x1c],eax
   0x00007ffff7ffaa8b <clock_gettime+155>:  mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0xffffffffffffd61e]        # 0x7ffff7ff80b0
   0x00007ffff7ffaa92 <clock_gettime+162>:  mov    QWORD PTR [rsi],rax
   0x00007ffff7ffaa95 <clock_gettime+165>:  mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rip+0xffffffffffffd5e9]        # 0x7ffff7ff8084
   0x00007ffff7ffaa9b <clock_gettime+171>:  mov    r10,QWORD PTR [rip+0xffffffffffffd616]        # 0x7ffff7ff80b8
   0x00007ffff7ffaaa2 <clock_gettime+178>:  cmp    edx,0x1
   0x00007ffff7ffaaa5 <clock_gettime+181>:  je     0x7ffff7ffabc0 <clock_gettime+464>
```

That I believe is the assembly for the following C code (from linux-4.8.0/arch/x86/include/asm/vgtod.h):

```
static inline unsigned gtod_read_begin(const struct vsyscall_gtod_data *s)
{
    unsigned ret;

repeat:
    ret = ACCESS_ONCE(s->seq);
    if (unlikely(ret & 1)) {
        cpu_relax();
        goto repeat;
    }
    smp_rmb();
    return ret;
}
```

(The assembly instruction `pause` matches the `cpu_relax()`)

As I understand it `struct vsyscall_gtod_data *s` is held in `rbx` and the address is read in this instruction:

```
mov    r12d,DWORD PTR [rbx]
```

Meaning that the debugged program can read this address, but when I try to examine it in gdb I get an error:

```
(gdb) x $rbx
0x7ffff7ff8080: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7ff8080
(gdb)
```

Any ideas of what's going on and how to examine that memory?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access a memory location that can be accessed only if you have "privilege level" 0 (OS level). Don't trust me on the name, I read it a couple of days ago on the Intel manual so I might get the jargon wrong, the concept should be right though.

I am not 100% sure that it would be enough to sudo, but trying will not hurt. I know some instruction counting registers have similar issues and they can be accessed from userspace if you sudo.